# social media sharing and tracking

Tags: facebook, twitter, tracking, pinterest

Is there a way to track when user visits our page from social media like facebook, twitter or pinterest?

is there a way to add some parameters to the url so that it will be easier to track?

Comment: U need to accept answers to receive better and quicker answers from next time. :)

Comment: I also wonder if this can be done by sharing the URL of your website and appending something like the word "facebook" to the URL and then tracking it with Google Analytics. Your URL would look something like this: https://yoursite.com/index.php?facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php  
  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  
?>
```

This tiny php script enables you to know from where the user came from.

**EDITS**

As nyshangal asked for jsp code

JSP

```
request.getHeader("Referer");
```

I am not good at JSP. After googling I found that this above code will return the referrer from where the user came from.

Thank you

Comment: I am using jsp, is there a way I can do that in jsp?

Comment: this solution works for first question, but still I am trying to find answer for adding a parameter when user visits from external social media.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

Google's [Campaign URL Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/campaign-url-builder/) is just what you need to add parameters and values to your URL and then easily track them using your Google Analytics platform. You can give your campaign an ID, a name, define a medium and even put in there a slogan/promo code, etc.

Then after you have created your link, post it in the social media you have defined for it and track it via the Google Analytics platform.